# Laravel Curl Async request

Tags: php, laravel, curl, asynchronous

I want to create an async request to my own Laravel API which is used to send multiple emails. I don't want to use Queues. I want to call a script which does the dirty work.

I am using Curl for the same but it does not call the script. please help.

```
$url = url('/').'/send-async';   
$c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);         // Don't retrieve headers
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);          // Don't retrieve the body
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);  
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
    $val = curl_exec( $c );
    $error = curl_error($c)."  ". curl_errno($c);
    $info = curl_getinfo($c);
    curl_close($c);
Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'\logs\daily.log');
Log::info(['Request'=>$url." ".$val." ".$error. " ".json_encode($info)]);

Response: {"url":"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/proj\\/public_html\\/","content_type":"text\\/html; charset=UTF-8","http_code":200,"header_size":1461,"request_size":258,"filetime":-1,"ssl_verify_result":0,"redirect_count":2,"total_time":2.813,"namelookup_time":3.0e-6,"connect_time":3.0e-6,"pretransfer_time":3.0e-6,"size_upload":0,"size_download":0,"speed_download":0,"speed_upload":0,"download_content_length":-1,"upload_content_length":-1,"starttransfer_time":2.813,"redirect_time":1.063,"redirect_url":"","primary_ip":"::1","certinfo":[],"primary_port":80,"local_ip":"::1","local_port":59177}',
```

)

I feel like though its sending http code 200, it does not reach the intended url.

And when i do file_get_contents of the same url, it returns the view code of `http://localhost/proj/public_html/` rather than returning the echoed response.

Comment: what's your url is?? try `dd($url)` and see if it match or not

Comment: I did...it is http://localhost/proj/public_html/send-async ... it works well on browser but when doing curl it returns the entire html code.